# How can I get error information when I test Android App in real mobile phone?

Tags: android, kotlin

You know I have to test android code in real mobile phone in some cases, such as I have to test Google in-app payment code in real mobile.

How can I get error information when I test Android App in real mobile phone? You know sometimes the App crash and exit quickly, I hardly see any error information?

BTW, is there global error caption fuction for Android App when I use kotlin in Android Studio 4.0?

Comment: Check your `targetSDKversion` and `minSDKversion`

Comment: Checkout Firebase Crashlytics https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/

Comment: You can see logs/errors in Logcat tab in Android Studio if the device is connected to computer via USB.